# Order by field in related model with ActiveRecord condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I am trying to order by a field in a related model in Rails. All of the solutions I have researched have not addressed if the related model is filtered by another parameter?

**Item model**

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :priorities
```

**Related Model:**

```
class Priority < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item

  validates :item_id, presence: true
  validates :company_id, presence: true
  validates :position, presence: true
end
```

I am retrieving Items using a where clause:

```
@items = Item.where('company_id = ? and approved = ?', @company.id, true).all
```

I need to order by the 'Position' column in the related table. The trouble has been that in the Priority model, an item could be listed for multiple companies. So the positions are dependent on which company_id they have. When I display the items, it is for one company, ordered by position within the company. What is the proper way to accomplish this? Any help is appreciated.

PS - I am aware of acts_as_list however found it did not quite suit my setup here, so I am manually handling saving the sorting while still using jquery ui sortable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the `includes` method to include the build association then order by it. You just make sure you disambiguate the field you are ordering on and there are some things you should read up on [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) on eager loading. So it could be something like:

```
@items = Item.includes(:priorities).where('company_id = ? and approved = ?', @company.id, true).order("priorities.position ASC")
```

Comment: This worked very well for me. Thanks, Jason! The only thing I had to add was 'items.company_id' to the where clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :priorities
  belongs_to :company
  def self.approved
    where(approved: true)
  end
end

class Priority < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
end

@company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
@items = @company.items.joins(:priorities).approved.order(priorities: :position)
```

If I've understood your question, that's how I'd do it. It doesn't really need much explanation but lemme know if you're not sure.

If you wanted to push more of it into the model, if it's a common requirement, you could scope the order:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :priorities
  belongs_to :company

  def self.approved
    where(approved: true)
  end

  def self.order_by_priority_position
    joins(:priorities).order(priorities: :position)
  end
end
```

and just use: `@company.items.approved.order_by_priority_position`